# I have bought Skyrim on CD, yet Steam is saying I have to buy it

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I bought Skyrim on CD a few months ago and had no trouble playing it, Steam recognized that I had purchased it

However, my computer crashed and I had to reinstall everything.

In the time between the computer crashing and me reinstalling, a friend shared their library with me and Skyrim also happened to be in that library. Now whenever I try to reinstall from the CD, Steam only has it in the shared library, meaning I can only play it when my friend is not using it. It's not unplayable, just very irritating that Steam is asking me to either purchase again or wait until the library is free.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or if I can install Skyrim not using Steam?

Comment: It sounds like Steam is only checking for Skyrim in your shared library and not for the one you have installed from CD. I don't know much about how shared libraries work but you could try unsharing the library and have steam then recognize your CD installed copy of Skyrim before going back to a shared library.

Answer (score 6):

In your CD Case there is also a key, when installing you should be prompted to enter that key. In case that does not happen you can fill in the key manually in Steam.